# Horizontal menu with fade effect on overflow

Tags: css, sass, overflow

I'm using CSS3/SASS and I wouldn't like to use any Javascript if possible. I'm trying to make a horizontal menu where overflow-x would make nice fade effect on the right side, so the user on mobile devices would know that he can move it left-right.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: nice fade on the right side text]

... as you can see on the picture the text on the right side is being faded out a bit and there, of course, is an OPTION3 menu item (so it's overflowed).

So far I got the menu, but I really have no idea about the overflows and the tricks with them.

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-list">
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">settings</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">option1</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">option2</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">option3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**SASS:**

```
.navbar
    float: left
    height: 40px
    min-width: 100%
    display: flex
    flex-wrap: wrap

    .navbar-item
        padding: 13px 0px
        font-size: 12px
        line-height: 14px
        text-transform: uppercase
        display: inline-block
        float: left
        margin: 0px 10px

        &.active
            padding: 13px 0px 11px 0px
            border-bottom: 2px solid $light-blue

        &:hover
            cursor: pointer

        a 
            color: $dark-grey
            font-weight: 600
            text-decoration: none
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `:before` and `:after` elements. (on a div with `width:100vh` for example)
You display one gradient on the left of your screen, and one on the right.

```
  content:'';
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1 );
```

This way, you will have a gradient hovering the edges of your menu.

To precise a bit more,

`.navbar` should have `overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;` and `navbar-list` should be 100% wide.

Comment: thank you, I already managed it but if you can, please add to your answer that the `.navbar` should have `overflow-x: auto;` and `white-space: nowrap` and also `.navbar-list` should be 100% wide.

Comment: Great! Thank you. It's just in case someone with the same problem will take a look on this one.

Comment: Yes, you're right.
I assumed that you would find a way, but I didn't think about other people.
I'm glad that you managed to do it. ;)